# create comparator for map<int, pair<int, int>>

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I have a `map<int, pair<int, int>>` and I want to store elements in descending order of `key`. In case of any equal value, I want `pair.first` to be less.

Example:

`10, {5, 10}` is smaller than `10, {6, 10}` and should be placed earlier?

PS - I am not a pro in C++

Comment: Change to `map<pair<int, int>, int>` and voila!

Comment: But I want to store `key` with descending order?

Comment: The thing is `map` doesn't order based on the value, but based on the key. You have to pick.

Comment: @DeiDei yes. So how do we write our own `comparator`?

Comment: Use `set` instead of `map`.

Comment: What will it do?

Comment: @Pubby so should it be `set<pair<int, pair<int, int>>>` ?

Answer (score 0):

A `map<Key, Value>` is ordered only on the key.  (like @DeiDei said)

So, there's no way to get the ordering you want with `map<int, pair<int, int>>`.  You'll have to use a different data structure.